# OneDrive (AKA SkyDrive) has corrupted my files

Tags: onedrive

I had pictures that I backed up to OneDrive. I recently did a system restore from Windows 8.1 back to Windows 8 Pro as well. This placed my OneDrive files into a Windows.old folder. These files are now corrupt. I can see that the files exists and it tells me the size of the files, but they will not open them. Is there anything that can be done to recover these files?

Comment: What actually happens when you try to open them?  Any error messages presented?  If so, what do they say? Anything in the Event Logs related to you trying to open it? If you copy/move them to a different folder do they behave the same way?

Comment: When you view the icons they have a grey x on them. VLC says it cannot open because of a bad file descriptor.  Most other programs say corrupt file.

Comment: The Grey X is the key. Again: If you copy/move them to a different folder do they behave the same way? Also, if you head to that folder via the command line, do the files show up when you do a `dir`? How much free space do you have on your hard drive?